# views intergration with redirect module

Tags: 7, views, redirection

I've googled and nothing found about redirect module integration into views to add **new filter criteria for a content type or taxonomy**.

I need all redirects (`FROM` and `To` fields that showing in the image) path against specific **nid** (contextual filter) or **content type** (blog, event, article).

For more clarifications, see attached image[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) has default views in `admin/structure/views` that fetchs all redirect URLs without any entity type filter neither you can add any relationship and nor filter criteria for any specific entity type.

So, we have to go programmatically way to achieve such scenario. See simple code below for content types only. If you want to go with any other entity type (like taxonomy), make changes in `foreach loop`

## CODE

```
$query = db_select('redirect', 'r');
$query->condition('r.type', 'redirect')
      ->fields('r', array('rid', 'redirect', 'redirect_options', 'source'));
$query->orderBy('rid', 'DESC');
$exe_query = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach($exe_query as $result => $key){
    $str_node = substr($key->redirect,0,4);
    $nid = substr($key->redirect,5);
    if($str_node == 'node' && is_numeric($nid)){
      $node =  node_load($nid);
      if($node->type == 'article' && $node->status == 1){
        //Do Something
      }
    }
}
```

Now, you can add this code in custom module.

*Very important, the `redirect_options` column in `redirect` table has all the URL's (where your source URL is going to redirect) parameters in serialize form. So, you have to unserialize it first and concat with `redirect` columns' output.*

Answer (score 3):

**For your first question:**

[Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) integrated with views module, just navigate to admin/structure/views and you will see View called **Redirects**, enable it if it's not enabled, then pick the field you want, source field label is 'Source redirect' and from is redirect URL.

[image: Default redirect view]

You can also create a new your view just be sure you using the base table or redirect

[image: Create new view based on Url redirects table]

---

**For the second question:**

you need first to understand how redirect module structured.

Each redirect record you see is an entity, and it has the following fields:

1. rid: Primary Key: Unique redirect ID.
2. hash: A unique hash based on source, source_options, and language.
3. type: The redirect type; if the value is 'redirect' it is a normal redirect handled by the module.
4. **uid**: The {users}.uid of the user who created the redirect.
5. source: The source path to redirect from.
6. source_options: A serialized array of source options.
7. redirect: The destination path to redirect to.
8. redirect_options: A serialized array of redirect options.
9. language: The language this redirect is for; if blank, the alias will be used for unknown languages.
10. status_code: The HTTP status code to use for the redirect.
11. count: The number of times the redirect has been used.
12. access: The timestamp of when the redirect was last accessed.
13. status: Boolean indicating whether the redirect is enabled (visible to non-administrators).

As you see from the structure, there is no reference to the entity you added the redirect for; you have only a reference for the user who creates the redirect.

You can create a relation between the redirect and the user who creates the redirect, then get the nodes which authored by that user; Then you can adjust the views in the way you want.

Please notice this would **work with nodes** and with **any entity store uid**, but for example, in **Taxonomy case it won't work** because taxonomy entity doesn't store the uid.

another tip might help a bit is to add the redirect URL as a filter then make some string comparison.

[image: redirect URL as filter for string comparison.]

Comment: Thanks and appreciate for the help. This view is getting all redirects of all content types, taxonomy etc. while I need to get only against a specific content type that isn't available in the filter criteria of redirect views and even I can't add it. How would I do that?

Comment: I have updated the question as well. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sandbox module called [Views Redirect Relationship](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/seewatson/2285335)  that provides the thing you might need.  It is now (2020) quite old (2014) and I wish it had been promoted to a full project by now because this is super useful for large sites.

I need this on Drupal 8 so I created an issue to get this officially released and a Drupal 8/9 update going:

https://www.drupal.org/project/2285335/issues/3171396