# Ability to show source url in Content view for nodes who have redirects associated with them

Tags: 8, views

I have a content view which displays all nodes on the site in a table with fields. Some of the nodes have redirects associated with them, which means that they have a source url associated with them.  I need to display the source url along with the other data in the original view table if it exists.

I planned to use view_hook_query_alter to join to the redirect table but it seems that there are not common fields that we can use to join the table.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253864/views-intergration-with-redirect-module